# Add a column to a BigQuery schema - but not at the end

Tags: google-bigquery

A few months ago it was possible to update the schema of a BigQuery table by

1. Dumping it via: `bq show --schema Dataset.table > table.json`
2. Then altering the schema and adding a column:

```
[                                                                  
  {                                                          
    "name": "A",                                                                                                                                      
    "type": "STRING"                 
  },
  {                                                          
    "name": "NEW_COLUMN",                                                                                                                                      
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {                                                          
    "name": "B",                                                                                                                                      
    "type": "STRING"                 
  }                           
]
```

3. Then updating the table via:
   `bq update Dataset.table table.json`

Finally the column would appear at exactly the specified place within the table's schema. Today I tried doing this on an existing table in our dataset and the column was added *at the end* as if I would have used an `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` statement. Is it possible to get the old behavior back? I used it a lot when I have little control about the schema changes of source tables that I consume in upstream tables.

Comment: I also tested with the python code without success

Comment: It seems to be the current behavior. It's not nice at all but what I ended up doing was the creation of a newly fresh table with the column order I want, and then move the data there. I could do it because it wasn't too much data but it's unfeasible if we have TBs as we pay for the SELECT * FROM...

Comment: @Alvaro exactly, my Table is a few TB's and most of the data is now long term storage. If I do the SELECT * FROM approach I will end up with a lot of active storage to pay for on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was possible, but was [never officially supported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182294542#comment2). So one has to use the workaround from now on.